How can the URL link after I http get got different in fluttter?
On the previous page, I had a list of news items that worked fine. When I clicked on a news item, it sent an index to fetch the next API post. However, every time I clicked on any item, it always took me to the same page. What's even more strange is that when I tried to modify the API ID, it still directed me to that same page. Initially, I thought there was no issue with the previous page, but the problem lies here. I tried to get the index as expected, and even the URL link matched my expectations. However, the problem arose when the HTTP GET response body changed afterward. I use adapter and view method in this page.
Description Adapter
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pukulenam/PartView/DescriptionView.dart';

import '../NavBar/BottomBar.dart';
import '../NavBar/TabIconData.dart';
import '../Themes/MainThemes.dart';

class DescriptionAdapter extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const DescriptionAdapter({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DescriptionAdapterState createState() => _DescriptionAdapterState();
}

class _DescriptionAdapterState extends State<DescriptionAdapter>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;
  late int index;
  List<TabIconData> tabIconsList = TabIconData.tabIconsList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabIconsList.forEach((TabIconData tab) {
      tab.isSelected = false;
    });
    index = widget.index;
    animationController = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 600),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFFF2F3F8),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<bool>(
              future: getData(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const SizedBox();
                } else {
                  return DescriptionView(
                    animationController: animationController,
                    activityIndex: index,
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
            bottomBar(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> getData() async {
    await Future<dynamic>.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    return true;
  }

  Widget bottomBar() {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const Expanded(
          child: SizedBox(),
        ),
        BottomBarView(
          tabIconsList: tabIconsList,
          addClick: () {},
          changeIndex: (int index) {
            if (index == 0) {
              animationController?.reverse().then<dynamic>((data) {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              });
            } else if (index == 1 || index == 3) {
              animationController?.reverse().then<dynamic>((data) {
                if (!mounted) {
                  return setState(() {});
                }
                setState(() {});
              });
            }
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Description View
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pukulenam/Models/NewsData.dart';
import '../Themes/MainThemes.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter_widget_from_html/flutter_widget_from_html.dart';

class DescriptionView extends StatefulWidget {
  const DescriptionView({
    Key? key,
    required this.animationController,
    required this.activityIndex,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final AnimationController? animationController;
  final int activityIndex;

  @override
  _DescriptionViewState createState() => _DescriptionViewState();
}

class _DescriptionViewState extends State<DescriptionView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController animationController;
  late Future<List<NewsData>> selectedActivity;
  late int activityIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    activityIndex = widget.activityIndex;
    animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
    );
    animationController.forward();
    selectedActivity = fetchNewsList();
  }

  Future<List<NewsData>> fetchNewsList() async {
    return http
        .get(
      Uri.parse('https://pukulenam.id/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?id=${activityIndex}'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization':
      },
    )
        .then((response) {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('activity indexnya padahal ${activityIndex}');
        List<NewsData> newsList = [];
        List<dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);

        data.forEach((item) {
          NewsData news = NewsData.fromJson(item);
          newsList.add(news);
        });

        return newsList;
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load news. Status Code: ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    }).catchError((error) {
      throw Exception('Failed to load news. Error: $error');
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget getAppBarUI(String name) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: animationController,
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
            return FadeTransition(
              opacity: animationController,
              child: Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                  0.0,
                  30 * (1.0 - animationController.value),
                  0.0,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: MainAppTheme.white.withOpacity(1.0),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(32.0),
                    ),
                    boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: MainAppTheme.grey.withOpacity(0.4),
                        offset: const Offset(1.1, 1.1),
                        blurRadius: 10.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SizedBox(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: ClipOval(
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 60,
                                  height: 60,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                  child: Image(
                                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/sayang.jpg'), // Default image
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 10), // Spacer
                            Expanded(
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    name,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                // Handle share button press
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 80.0),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            FutureBuilder<List<NewsData>>(
              future: selectedActivity,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Center(child: Text('Failed to load news'));
                } else if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.isNotEmpty) {
                  final newsData = snapshot.data![0];
                  var document = HtmlWidget(newsData.content!);

                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      getAppBarUI(newsData.author ?? 'Unknown Author'),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                          children: [
                            if (newsData.imageUrl != null)
                              Container(
                                height: 200, // Adjust height as needed
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(newsData.imageUrl!),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10),
                            if (newsData.title != null)
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                                child: Text(
                                  newsData.title!,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 16,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            SizedBox(height: 30),
                            if (newsData.content != null)
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                                child: document,
                              ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                } else {
                  return Center(child: Text('No data available'));
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


and the funny console log I got:

I/flutter (28268): 2422
I/flutter (28268): test
I/flutter (28268): linknya seharusnya ini https://pukulenam.id/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?id=2422
I/flutter (28268): https://pukulenam.id/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?id=2422
I/flutter (28268): [{"id":2447,"

see it has different id in response body
I expecting the response body has same as the api id they got from before page
